# Change Default Browser on Reboot without GPO

Tags: windows-10, browser, group-policy

in my company we have now decided to use MS Edge as default browser for everyone.
I am allowed to use my own browser, but our client administrator has rolled out a GPO to set the default browser to edge as soon as I log in.
The browser I want to set it to is Brave.

I think I am overcomplicating things but here where my two Ideas ´til now:
Setting it back in registry with powershell: too much work but I would do if not otherwise possible
I also had the idea to set it to Brave via --make-default-browser in the Task Scheduler as a log in event. But I tried that over the commandline before it is sadly not working.

I am not very windows proficient so it would be nice if someone has an answer and I also could learn something new.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If you have access to regedit / running reg scripts, a registry script in your startup folder might be the most foolproof/simplest way

Comment: Administrator represents the organization on your computer. What they say goes. You're asking us to help circumvent organization policies.

Comment: @music2myear as already mentioned i am allowed to install and use my own browser. The policy to use Edge is to unify the clients to make it easier for the helpdesk to identify problems. The group policy is rolled out on everyone also to make it easy. I am software engineer and also server and client administrator (long story ). And even if I would be not allowed to do it by company rules I would still be interested how to do it.

Comment: @InterLinked Yeah but as it seems this only works after a reboot. At least for what I found. And after reboot / login the group policy runs again. Do you have a source / link for a script or an article where this is described ?

Comment: @music2myear I've been in similar situations, where I basically roll my own login scripts to tweak things the way I like from the way the default is. It's not that it's locked down because some of the settings can be changed interactively, but doing so is annoying, hence scripting it